# computations of limits of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Assume that we have $ \lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+1/x^2 \right)^{x} $.  So clearly it goes to $1$ because $x=O(x^2)$. But more rigorously, what are the requirements that are needed to write it like
$$
(\lim_{x\to \infty}(1+1/x^2)^{x^2})^{\lim 1/x}=e^{0}=1 ?
$$
Are these steps legitimate for any continuous function? Is a.e continuity is suffice too?

Comment: The most straightforward approach to such problems is to consider the logarithm of given expression. Thus if $F(x) = \{f(x)\}^{g(x)}$ then try to find the limit of $\log F(x) = g(x)\log f(x)$. If $\log F(x) \to L$ then $F(x) \to e^{L}$ and if $\log F(x) \to -\infty$ then $F(x) \to 0$ and if $\log F(x) \to \infty$ then $F(x) \to \infty$.